# Not able to use Multi processing for a Nested for loop function in Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, function, for-loop, jupyter-notebook, python-multiprocessing

I tried Multiple techniques to use multiple processing but failed. Normal for loop is taking days to execute and I may have done something wrong or the code is not optimized.

```
    for i in range(0,len(Years)):
        colname = int(Years[i])
        Status[str(colname)] = ''
        for j in range(0,len(Unique_ID)):
            sample = SA_data[SA_data.accountID==Unique_ID[j]]
            Status.loc[j, 'accountID'] = Unique_ID[j]
            Status.loc[j, str(colname)] = np.where((((sample['YearMonth_Start'].values)<colname) & ((sample['saStatus'].values)=='Active')).any(),'True',
                          np.where((((sample['YearMonth_Start'].values)<colname) & ((sample['YearMonth_End'].values)>colname) ).any(),'True','False'))
```

I want to execute this piece of code in minimum time as possible. So I thought multiple processing would be the best option.
Unique_ID has around 360000 ID's and Years has total 16 rows. I am not even able to put that in a proper function to use map function and run parallel. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you are using pandas, I think you should group the SA_data by its accountID column i.e. `SA_data.groupby('accountID')` and then use its apply function to apply a function to each group. This way you will drop one of the for loops. Your code sweeps over SA_data, 16*360000 times (so every row of SA_data  is iterated 16*360000 times), but with groupby, the code will iterate each row 17 times only(16 times for each year plus one time during the groupby).

Comment: @Ali_MM Thanks a million. It worked like a charm. I just had one more thing to ask that right now it takes 20 mins. So is there any way I can use multiprocessing or parallel processing in order to shorten the execution time. Thanks again